# Center elements css html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery datepicker implemented. Above some days I show some colour dots. This dots represent information of that day.

I am having problemes with the css.

I want to center the dots with the number. If I do that then, the days with dots, aren't align horizontally with the other days. I have added a photo that represents that. The days 22, 23, 24, 28, 29, 16, 17 that have dots aren't aling with the others days.

How I can align the days with dots?

[image]

```
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2020"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2020"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a>
    <div class="dot-container">
        <div class="dot orange"></div>
        <div class="dot black"></div>
        <div class="dot red"></div>
        <div class="dot blue"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2020"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a>
    <div class="dot-container">
        <div class="dot black"></div>
        <div class="dot orange"></div>
        <div class="dot yellow"></div>
        <div class="dot red"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

```
.ui-state-default{
    text-align:center !important;
}

.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.dot{
  width: 7px !important; 
  height: 7px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;

}

@media (max-width: 450px) { 
    .dot{
         width: 5px !important; 
         height: 5px !important;
         border-radius: 50%;
         display: inline-block;
         margin-right: 2px;
    }
 }
.red{
   background-color: red !important;
}
.blue{
   background-color: blue !important;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

.green{
     background-color: green !important;
}
.black{background-color: black !important;}
.orange{background-color: orange !important;}


.ui-datepicker .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: none !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    max-width: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

I have tried by adding to the dot-container class the attribute position:absolute. If I do that all the day numbers are aligned but then aren't centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems so easy

```
td{
    position: relative;
}
.dot-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;

}
```

second way: (following @saran)

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: I have trid this, and it doesn't center the dots. They appeared on the left.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ptvuzm0b/  Yes, if you see the days with dots they aren't align.

Comment: And how the background colour of the day 16, the day 17, does'nt fit all the day cell ? I have to define a max-width? But then it wouldnt be centered

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS property vertical-align for td

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```